# How to solve Error code: '404', Message: 'The requested resource doesn't exist when adding a row to an excel file using azure logic apps?

Tags: excel, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to store the result of a form in a Hugo website to an excel file.
I think that the problem might be with the sharing permissions since for some reason when I go to the file I cant click on share with everyone. I'm using office for business.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, you can't input `Sheet1` into the "**Table**" box because sheet doesn't belong to table. In my test, when I input `Sheet1` as custom value, it will show same error message as yours.

You need to go to your excel and click "**Insert**" --> "**Table**" to insert a table to your excel.

[image]

Then we can select the table in the drop-down box of "**Table**".

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solved mey problem. However Im still getting an error A value must be provided for item.\r\nclientRequestId. Do you have any idea what can I do? Here are some links with images of what I have https://lambdacapitalxyz-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/eduardo_lambdacapital_xyz/ElYcTsicXwBPhNcuXd1i5i4B3XRcQCLizQRAAubrGMVI2w?e=k6C8hi. Thanks.

Comment: @tlalco Sorry for delay, I reproduced the error message if I don't input row content into the action. When I input the row content into it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI2Br.png), it works fine.